# Flutter - TimeOfDay - how to set locale

Tags: flutter, localization

I have a Flutter multi-lingual app. It has a language selector, which allows to select a language among predefined list.
I successfully handle loading of my text labels.
I have however two major classes, where I have to manually set locale, when the user changes it:

- `DateTime` and more specifically its formatting methods e.g. `DateFormat.MMMEd([locale])`. This one however is easy, since it supports locale as parameter. I have no issue with it;
- `TimeOfDay` - it has `format(context)` method, however this method formats `TimeOfDay` instance according to `MaterialLocalizations.formatTimeOfDay` method internally to format the time and I cannot see how I can pass currently selected app locale.

So my question basically is how to set locale, when `TimeOfDay.format` method is executed?

The other related to above is `showTimePicker`, but I guess both inquires will have the same solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there are two missing pieces, which fix the issue:

1. Set `locale` value in when call `MaterialApp`, e.g.

:

```
MaterialApp( 
  title: Env.value.appName,

  locale: allTranslations.locale,
  ...
);
```

2. When the user changes `locale`, I have to call `setState` and rebuild the app, hence new locale to be propagated properly.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with locales, And I figured out it's better not to depend on flutter's locale. I'm using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) library to save the current locale that the user choose, and I can access it in my entire app. so basically you better save the locale in shared preference when the user decides the language. hope it helps

Comment: This is not related to what I am asking for - no matter if you save locale in shared preferences or use the one Flutter internally has, if you are using locale dependent classes e.g. `TimeOfDay` you will run into the identical issue as long as you cannot tell the app to change locale for Flutter locale dependent classes.